# Characterization of diagonal/off-diagonal part of $\operatorname{End}(G)$ for finite abelian group $G$

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

Let $G$ be a finite abelian group and $\operatorname{End}(G)$ (resp. $\operatorname{Sym}(G)$) the (symmetric) endomorphism ring on $G$.
Of course as a product of rings, $G$ is a ring itself. If we choose a factor decomposition of $G$, we can embed $G$ itself into $\operatorname{End}(G)$ (resp. $\operatorname{Sym}(G)$) as "diagonal matrices". I am pretty sure that this embedding preserves the ring structure and doesn't depend on the factor decomposition of $G$.

- How does this embedding look without using a factor decomposition?
- Is there also a nice characterization of the "off-diagonal" matrices as an ideal in $\operatorname{End}(G)$ (resp. $\operatorname{Sym}(G)$)? In total I am basically looking for a nice coordinate-freely defined exact sequence of abelian subgroups of $\operatorname{End}(G)$ (resp. $\operatorname{Sym}(G)$).

Feel free to use duals whenever needed. I know that this question is a little bit special interest, so I don't expect a lot of attention ;) I hope it's still okay.

Answer (score 1):

You've stated your question confusingly; you say it's about a finite abelian group but what you are really doing is considering a finite direct product of finite cyclic groups $C_n$ and then interpreting that product as the same product but over finite cyclic rings $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$. These are not the same mathematical structure and if the latter is what you care about then you should talk about that from the start.

Anyway, if $R$ is any ring whatsoever, it naturally acts on itself by left multiplication, and this gives a canonical embedding of $R$ into $\text{End}_{\mathbb{Z}}(R)$. If $R$ is a finite product of finite cyclic rings $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ then this is the embedding of diagonal matrices. It requires no factor decomposition to write down.

The off-diagonal matrices don't form an ideal and I don't know what you mean by "symmetric." Are you taking the transpose of the matrices?

Comment: Oh, you are completely right, sorry for the confusion. I'll edit it later. Yes, by symmetric I meant invariant under transposition.

Comment: Also yes, the off diagonals are not an ideal, but rather a $G$-module. Embarassing. However, the inclusion of rings $G \to \operatorname{End}(G)$ is split for the underlying abelian groups, so there should be a subgroup $\operatorname{OffDiag}(G)$ of $\operatorname{End}(G)$ which I wanted to characterize without a factor decomposition.